# incompatible types: View cannot be converted to RadioButton

Tags: android

`RadioButton` selection from `RadioGroup` is not working;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_button);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            Toast.makeText(RadioButton.this, radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

See error.

[image: error in view]

[image: error in getText]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check which radio button you are using. I think you are using some library which has their own **RadioButton**. Remove that one and write again and check you are using which import.

**RadioButton** must be from **android.widget**.

for e.g.

```
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
```

Comment: Thanks, did a stupid mistake like setting the Activity name RadioButton.